# req.cookies is [Object: null prototype] {} on express router on server it is working in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, jwt, refresh-token

this is my server side code in which i am requesting cookies. I am getting the cookies in localhost but i am not getting it when it is being deployed. i have used withCredentials:true on my frontend code but then also i am not getting the cookies

````
  const cookies=req.cookies;
  console.log(cookies);
  if(!cookies?.jwt){
    return res.status(401).send({message:"Unauthorized"})
  }
  const refreshToken=cookies.jwt;
  jwt.verify(refreshToken,process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
    asyncHandler(async (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) return res.status(403).json({ message: "Forbidden" });

      const foundUser = await User.findOne({
        username: decoded.username,
      }).exec();

      if (!foundUser) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
      const payload= {
        username: foundUser.username,
        role: foundUser.role,
      }
      const token = generateJwtToken(
        payload,
         "15m" 
      );

      res.json({ token });
    }))
}
const whoAmIController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = req.user;
console.log(user);

    res.status(200).json({ user });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Something Went Wrong",
    });
  }
};```




**this is my cors configuration**
````

const corsOptions = {
origin: "https://dev.d2c7oi8mimsn0e.amplifyapp.com",
optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));